# Python - Parsing a Lexical Grammar without a Parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, lexical-analysis, bnf

I've got a bit of a chicken-egg problem for you. I'm wondering what the "correct" way — the "academically substantiated" way of solving it is.

I'm building a lexer generator to supply tokens to a parser. As with most such tools, I need to convert a lexical grammer in BNF form to a series of regular expressions and then to a DFA.

Here's the problem: I need a parser to parse the grammar so I can in turn use it to build the lexer, so I can ultimately build the parser. Chicken, meet egg.

There are three possible avenues I can think of:

```
1. Build a mini parser (probably a combinator). Going this route, I wonder to myself why I'd bother building the lexer (generator) in the first place.

2. Dissect the BNF by hand. This is further complicated by the fact that I refuse outright to use any existing string manipulation infrastructure. I'm trying to put myself into the headspace of an early, early coder (armed with no tools beyond a for-loop and an if-statement). 

3. Don't use a grammar, but rather, supply the individual regular expressions for each token type manually (basically, bypass the BNF-to-Set-of-Rules conversion). This approach is probably the best, but it is a bit anticlimactic.
```

In a nutshell, how do I dissect my BNF lexical grammar without a parsing infrastructure in place already?

Dissecting the BNF by hand, supplying the individual expressions. Have not yet, but am prepared to try to build a miniature preparser if needed.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to start with a BNF grammar? You could just start with regular expressions. And you can construct an NFA directly from the textual representation of the regular expression, although it does help to keep the positions of open parentheses on a stack.

Comment: Actually, parsing BNF is almost trivial, but you do need to divide the BNF representation into lexemes. So you're going to end up handcoding something somewhere.

Comment: I'd say #1 is the best approach even though it touches on #2 as a possible solution (you'll have to manipulate strings anyway). #3 is the worse, RE can become quite uncontrollable if you let them. Assuming that the lexer will be usefull elsewhere, it pays to have a dedicated language on which users could write their lexing needs on.